# What to change in the index.html code so it can work in offline mode on computer?

Tags: html

What to change in the index.html code so it can work in offline mode on computer?
At the bottom of page I change:

```
 <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/recorder.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/tuna.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/drumbit.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

those from above are changed into:

```
 <script src="file:C:/Users/nebojsa/Downloads/123/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="file:C:/Users/nebojsa/Downloads/123/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="file:C:/Users/nebojsa/Downloads/123/js/recorder.js"></script>
  <script src="file:C:/Users/nebojsa/Downloads/123/js/tuna.js"></script>
  <script src="file:C:/Users/nebojsa/Downloads/123/js/drumbit.js"></script>
</body>
</html
```

But it still won't work what from the rest of the code should be changed in directory path or something else so it start working in offline mode? html code of index page is below:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>drumbit</title>
  <link href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="title-bar-buttons">
      <button id="mini-app"></button>
      <button id="close-app"></button>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="preload">
    <img src="css/images/preloader.gif">
  </div>       
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="control">  
      <div class="master-control"><!-- master vol, tempo, kits -->
        <p>
          <i class="vol-icon fa fa-volume-up"></i>
          <span>Master volume</span> 
        </p>
        <span class="tooltip-master-vol"></span> <!-- Tooltip -->
        <div id="master-vol"></div>
        <p>
          <i class="metronome-icon"></i>
          <span>Tempo</span> 
        </p>
        <input id="tempo"> bpm
        <div class="swing">
          <span class="swing-label">Swing</span>
          <span class="tooltip-swing-factor"></span> <!-- Tooltip -->
          <div id="swing-factor"></div> 
        </div>    
        <div class="drum-kits">
          <div class="preload-kit">
            <img src="css/images/preloader.gif">
          </div>            
          <select id="kits"></select>
        </div>    
        <div class="impulse-responses">
          <div class="preload-impulse">
            <img src="css/images/preloader.gif">
          </div>             
          <select id="impulses"></select>
          <div class="effects-level">     
            <span class="tooltip-convolver-level"></span> <!-- Tooltip -->
            <div id="convolver-level"></div>      
          </div>           
        </div>  
        <div class="demos-and-filters">
          <select id="demos">
            <option value="none">No Demo</option>
            <option value="rock">Rock</option>
            <option value="rock2">Rock II</option>
            <option value="funk">Funk</option>
            <option value="funk2">Funk II</option>
            <option value="bossa">Bossa Nova</option>
            <option value="hip-hop">Hip-Hop</option>
          </select>  
          <table class="filters-leds">
            <tr>
              <td><button id="lowpass-led"></button></td>
              <td><span>Low</span></td>
              <td><button id="highpass-led"></button></td>
              <td><span>High Pass</span></td>
            </tr>              
            <tr>
              <td><button id="compressor-led"></button></td>
              <td colspan="3"><span>Compressor</span></td>
            </tr>  
          </table>
        </div>                   
      </div> 
      
      <div class="visual-eq"><!-- visualizer -->
        <div class="eq-colors">
          <div class="eq-color" id="red"></div>
          <div class="eq-color" id="yellow"></div>
          <div class="eq-color" id="purple"></div>
          <div class="eq-color" id="green"></div>  
        </div>
        <div id="marketing">
          <div></div>
      </div>       
        <canvas height="170" width="375" class="visualizer"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="options">
        <button tabindex="-1" class="btn-panels" id="panning" data-tooltip="Left-right distribution"><i class="fa fa-sliders" aria-hidden="true"></i> Panning</button>
        <button tabindex="-1" class="btn-panels" id="filtering" data-tooltip="Audio equalization"><i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Filters</button>
        <button tabindex="-1" class="btn-panels" id="preferences" data-tooltip="Startup defaults"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i> Preferences</button>
        <a tabindex="-1" id="plus" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/drumbit-plus/ibljjpnohhiphakedmfkklinogeomelb"
          target="_blank" data-tooltip="Plus edition"><i class="fa fa-chrome" aria-hidden="true"></i> Plus</a>            
        <a tabindex="-1" id="help" href="https://drumbit.app/help/?edition=free" target="_blank" data-tooltip="Help page"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Help</a>
      </div>      
      <div class="features"><!-- open, save, play, etc -->
        <h1>
          <img id="logo" src="css/images/drumbit-logo.png" alt="drumbit" />
          <span>by <a href="https://pluraldev.com/apps/" target = "_blank">João Santos</a></span>
        </h1>
        <div class="row-a">
          <div id="gen-wav">Generating sound file...</div>
          <div id="rec">REC <span id="minutes">00</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span></div>
          <button tabindex="-1" id="open" data-tooltip="Open file"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i></button>
          <button tabindex="-1" id="save" data-tooltip="Save file"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i></button>
          <button tabindex="-1" id="clear-all" data-tooltip="Clear all"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
          <button tabindex="-1" id="clear" data-tooltip="Clear"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></button>
          <button tabindex="-1" id="record"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></button>  
        </div>
        <div class="row-b">
          <div class="copy-paste"><span id="copy">Copy</span><span id="paste">Paste</span></div>
          <button id="pattern-0" class="patterns">1</button>
          <button id="pattern-1" class="patterns">2</button>
          <button id="pattern-2" class="patterns">3</button>
          <button id="pattern-3" class="patterns">4</button>
          <button id="play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>          
        </div>  
        <div class="ads">
          
        </div>     
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="machine">
      <div id="sequencer"> 
        <div class="preload-file">
          <img src="css/images/preloader.gif">
        </div>          
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Panel -->
    <!-- preferences -->
    <div class="panel preferences-panel">
      <span id="close-preferences" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"></span>
      <div>
        <label>Master Vol.</label><input id="default-master-vol">
        <span class="pref-tempo"><label>Tempo</label><input id="default-tempo"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="pref-default-kit">
        <select id="default-kit"></select>        
      </div>  
      <div class="pref-reset">
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
      </div>        
      <div class="pref-tooltips">
        <label>Tooltips</label><input type="checkbox" class="custom-check" id="default-tooltips">
        <span>*take effect after restart</span>
      </div>
      <!-- <span id="current-version"></span> -->
      <button id="save-preferences">OK</button>
    </div>       
    
    <!-- panning -->
    <div class="panel panning-panel">
      <span id="close-panning" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"></span>
      <div class="trk-pans">
        <p class="trk-name-0"></p>
        <p class="trk-name-1"></p>
        <p class="trk-name-2"></p>
        <p class="trk-name-3"></p>
        <p class="trk-name-4"></p>
        <p class="trk-name-5"></p>
        <p class="trk-name-6"></p>
        <p class="trk-name-7"></p>      
      </div>
      <div id="pan"></div>
    </div>    
    
    <!-- filters -->
    <div class="panel filters-panel">
      <span id="close-filters" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"></span>
      <select id="filters"></select>
      <div class="filter">
        <div id="compressor">
          <div id="add-compressor">
            <input type="radio" id="compressor-on" name="compressor"><label for="compressor-on">ON</label>
            <input type="radio" id="compressor-off" name="compressor" checked="checked"><label for="compressor-off">OFF</label>
          </div>
          <div class="filter-levels">
            <div class="filter-level">
              <label>Threshold</label>
              <span class="tooltip-compressor-threshold"></span> <!-- Tooltip --> 
              <div id="compressor-threshold"></div> <span class="filter-unit">dB</span>              
            </div>
            <div class="filter-level">
              <label>Ratio</label>
              <span class="tooltip-compressor-ratio"></span> <!-- Tooltip -->           
              <div id="compressor-ratio"></div> <span class="filter-unit">:1</span>                 
            </div>
            <div class="filter-level">
              <label>Attack</label>
              <span class="tooltip-compressor-attack"></span> <!-- Tooltip -->            
              <div id="compressor-attack"></div> <span class="filter-unit">ms</span>                
            </div>
            <div class="filter-level">
              <label>Release</label>
              <span class="tooltip-compressor-release"></span> <!-- Tooltip -->             
              <div id="compressor-release"></div> <span class="filter-unit">ms</span>                   
            </div>          
            <div class="filter-level">
              <label>Knee</label>
              <span class="tooltip-compressor-knee"></span> <!-- Tooltip -->         
              <div id="compressor-knee"></div> <span class="filter-unit">dB</span>    
            </div>           
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="lowpass">
          <div id="add-lowpass">
            <input type="radio" id="lowpass-on" name="lowpass"><label for="lowpass-on">ON</label>
            <input type="radio" id="lowpass-off" name="lowpass" checked="checked"><label for="lowpass-off">OFF</label>
          </div> 
          <div class="filter-levels">
            <div class="filter-level">
              <label>Frequency</label>
              <span class="tooltip-lowpass-frequency"></span> <!-- Tooltip --> 
              <div id="lowpass-frequency"></div> <span class="filter-unit">Hz</span>              
            </div>
            <div class="filter-level">
              <label>Q</label>
              <span class="tooltip-lowpass-q"></span> <!-- Tooltip -->           
              <div id="lowpass-q"></div> <span class="filter-unit"></span>                 
            </div>          
          </div>        
        </div>    
        <div id="highpass">
          <div id="add-highpass">
            <input type="radio" id="highpass-on" name="highpass"><label for="highpass-on">ON</label>
            <input type="radio" id="highpass-off" name="highpass" checked="checked"><label for="highpass-off">OFF</label>
          </div> 
          <div class="filter-levels">
            <div class="filter-level">
              <label>Frequency</label>
              <span class="tooltip-highpass-frequency"></span> <!-- Tooltip --> 
              <div id="highpass-frequency"></div> <span class="filter-unit">Hz</span>              
            </div>
            <div class="filter-level">
              <label>Q</label>
              <span class="tooltip-highpass-q"></span> <!-- Tooltip -->           
              <div id="highpass-q"></div> <span class="filter-unit"></span>                 
            </div>          
          </div>    
        </div>       
      </div>
    </div>   
    
    <!-- Invalid File Dialog -->
    <div id="invalid-file-dialog" title="Open File">
      <p></p>
    </div>     
    <!-- Reset Dialog --> 
    <div id="reset-dialog" title="Reset">
      <p>
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
        This action will reset all settings to their defaults.
      </p>     
    </div>  
      
    <!-- Clear Dialog -->  
    <div id="clear-dialog" title="Clear all">
      <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
      <p>
        This action will clear all the patterns along with panning, volumes and pitches.
      </p>
      <label>Don't show again</label><input type="checkbox" class="custom-check" id="clear-show">
    </div>   
  
    <!-- Notice -->  
    <div id="notice-dialog" title="Important notice">
      <p>
          No more new features will be added to this edition. The <a href="https://drumbit.app" target="_blank">Web App</a>, 
          also free and compatible with all modern browsers, and the  <a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/drumbit-plus/ibljjpnohhiphakedmfkklinogeomelb" target="_blank">drumbit Plus edition</a>, will continue to move forward. Please, consider using them instead.      
      </p>
      <p>
        Checkout the new features, including "Keys mode" on <a href="https://drumbit.app" target="_blank">drumbit.app</a>.
      </p>
      <label>Don't show again</label><input type="checkbox" class="custom-check" id="notice-show">
    </div>   
       
  </div><!--/ wrapper -->
  
  <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/recorder.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/tuna.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/drumbit.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What isn't working with the original code?

Comment: Remove the leading slash and the page will work with relative links: `<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>` will look for the js folder under the folder where the index.html page lives. You already have that for the css: `<link href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: That is not the solution. I try that also but it won't work. Something else in the code should be changed but I don't know what is it?

Comment: This is just HTML with Javascript, so storing it locally, and using relative paths for linked resources everywhere, should work.

Comment: Assuming you have a folder called `C:/Users/nebojsa/Downloads/123` and in that folder you have an `index.html` and two folders called `js` and `css` then removing the leading `/` from `/js` in your index.html (or what you call it) will make the page work UNLESS of course drumbit or recorder or other files MUST access the internet or some other folder you did not mention. Also it is very possible that you have a import statement in the css files that also wants to access the internet

Comment: Browser will not load files from file:// if the html file itself was not loaded from file://